# How do i make a clickable listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

i have a list of users that are bound to a listbox(image and the name of the user) and i want to render this lisbox clickable so whnever i click on a user's image i will be redirected
to his account.
this is the user control that displays the users:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Navigateur.Presentation.UserControlWork.ListeEnfControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Navigateur.Presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
             >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <conv:ByteArrayToImageConverter x:Key="bytearraytoImageConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid >
        <ListBox x:Name="_imageList" Margin="10,10,10,0" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="250" BorderThickness="0" MouseLeftButtonDown="Click_Kid" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="Enfant">
                    <Border CornerRadius="30">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Image Grid.Row="0" x:Name="image" Source="{Binding avatar}" Width="50" Height="80"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="nom" Text="{Binding prenom}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Button in place of Image and **override template of Button to give it an Image look**, so that you can have clickable image.

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Width="50" Height="80">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding avatar}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

If you are using `MVVM`, you can bind Command with button OR if want to do in code behind you can hook Click event of button to determine which image is clicked on.